# Unable to properly add an attachment - part of headers are added to file

Tags: php, email, base64, mime-types, email-attachments

I want to send an email with a pdf attachment using PHP's mail(). The problem is that in the end my attachment file is unreadable, because instead of decoding it from base64, part of headers are appended to it. My guess is that I'm concatenating headers in wrong way, but I tried to change it in various ways and result was always the same.

This is the final mail content I get in plain text:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: XXX - xxxxx <xxxx.xxxx@xxxxx.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=_x27e6cd8de4c00e2104105d5353947a1b0ca2a770x

This is a MIME encoded message.

--_x27e6cd8de4c00e2104105d5353947a1b0ca2a770x
Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

Verification Email
To activate the account click on the following link or copy-paste it in your browser:
http://10.24.35.92:443/?ctrl=users&act=verify&id=174&hash=4e4b5fbbbb602b6d35bea8460aa8f8e5

--_x27e6cd8de4c00e2104105d5353947a1b0ca2a770x
Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8

<h4>Verification Email</h4>
<table>
<tr><td>To activate the account click on the following link or copy-paste it in your browser:</td></tr>
<tr><td>http://10.24.35.92:443/?ctrl=users&act=verify&id=174&hash=4e4b5fbbbb602b6d35bea8460aa8f8e5</td></tr>

--_x27e6cd8de4c00e2104105d5353947a1b0ca2a770x
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="xxxx.pdf"; 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64; 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxxx.pdf";

(here goes the encoded attachment)
JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFu
MDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMTUzODUwIDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAxNzM4NzUgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDE3NDEw
MSAwMDAwMCBuDQp0cmFpbGVyDQo8PC9TaXplIDIxOS9Sb290IDEgMCBSL0luZm8gMzEgMCBSL0lE
(...)

--_x27e6cd8de4c00e2104105d5353947a1b0ca2a770x--
```

and this is how the pdf attachment looks like in text editor:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64;

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxxx.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFu
Zyhlbi1VUykgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDMyIDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4+
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the multipart/mixed MIME type. Something like this should works:

```
<form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
 <label for="name">Your Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />  
 <label for="email">Your Email</label> 
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
 <label for="myfile">Attachment</label>
 <input type="file" id="myfile" name="my_file" />
 <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP CODE

```
if($_POST && isset($_FILES['my_file'])){

$from_email = 'example@senderMail.com'; 
$to = 'to_mail@example.com'; 
$subject = 'Test mail with attachment'; 
$message = 'This is body of the message'; 

//get file details we need
$file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
$file_name        = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
$file_size        = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
$file_type        = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
$file_error       = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

$user_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

if($file_error>0)
{
    die('upload error');
}
//read from the uploaded file
$handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
//encode it with MIME base64, and split it into smaller chunks
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

//create a boundary string. It must be unique, you can use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
$boundary = md5(date('r', time()));  
//header
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

//plain text 
$body = "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

//attachment
$body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name="$file_name"\r\n";
$body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$file_name"\r\n";
$body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
$body .= $encoded_content; 

$sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
{       
    die('Thank you for your email');
}else{
    die('Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.');  
}

}
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
Vince.

Comment: I am using multipart/mixed MIME type in 3rd line.

Comment: Ah right. Try that code. Otherwise paste your code so i can have a look.